# Open link in new tab ContextMenuStrip with CefSharp and EasyTabs

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to make a fully-featured web browser in C# using the chromium embedded framework also known as CefSharp. For the tab control, I am using EasyTabs.
I want to have a custom context menu strip that has a "Open link in new tab" menu item.
This is what I have tried, but nothing happens when you run the application and click Open link in new tab.
I'd  appreciate any help I can get.

```
if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)OpenLinkInNewTab )
        {

                ResistBrowser.frmMain form;

                ResistBrowser.AppContainer appcontainer1;

                appcontainer1 = new ResistBrowser.AppContainer();

                form = new ResistBrowser.frmMain();


                browserControl.Load(parameters.SelectionText);

                appcontainer1.Tabs.Add(
               // Our First Tab created by default in the Application will have as content the Form1
               new TitleBarTab(appcontainer1)
               {
                   Content = new ResistBrowser.frmMain
                   {
                       Text = form.Text
                   }
               }
           );

            }
```

Comment: If this is called within your menu handler then you'll need to marshal your calls onto the WinForms UI thread. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=net-5.0 You can cast IWebBrowser to ChromiumWebBrowser and call BeginInvoke